# Método jquery não passa parâmetros para controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Jquery não passa parâmetros para controller. Está vindo em branco os valores.

Jquery:

```
function GravaEvento() {    
var str = "";
var parametros = jQuery.parseJSON('{ "DE_Cnpj": "' + $("#txtCnpj").val() + '" , "DE_Descricao": "' + $("#txtDescricao").val() + '" , "DE_UsuProxAcao": "' + $("#txtUsuarioProxAcao").val()
                                    + '" , "DE_UsuProxAcao": "' + $("#txtProxAcao").val() + '" , "DT_ProxAcao": "' + $("#txtDataCadastro").val()
                                    + '" , "ID_TipoProxAcao": "' + $("#txtDataCadastro").val() + '" }');

$.ajax({
    url: '/GerenciarPDV/GravaEvento',
    datatype: 'json',
    contentType: 'applicatio/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ _evento: parametros }),
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function () {

    }})
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GravaEvento(T_CRM_Evento _evento)
{
    V99_WEBEntities db = new V99_WEBEntities();
    T_TecnicoExterno user = new T_TecnicoExterno();
    user = (T_TecnicoExterno)SessaoUtil.Recuperar("sessionUser");
    try
    {
        T_CRM_Evento evento = new T_CRM_Evento();

        evento.DE_Cnpj = _evento.DE_Cnpj;
        evento.DE_Descricao = _evento.DE_Descricao;
        evento.DE_Usuario = user.DE_Login;
        evento.DE_UsuProxAcao = _evento.DE_UsuProxAcao;
        evento.DT_Inclusao = DateTime.Now;
        evento.DT_ProxAcao = _evento.DT_ProxAcao;
        evento.ID_TipoProxAcao = _evento.ID_TipoProxAcao;

        db.T_CRM_Evento.Add(evento);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string erro = ex.Message;
    }
    return Json(new { }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

A função chama a controller, porem não passa os valores. O `T_TecnicoExterno` é uma entidade do BD mapeada pelo meu Entity. Pensei em criar um objeto com os mesmos campos, mas achei isso repetir o que já existe ou não?

Jquery

```
function GravaEvento() {
    var parametros = { _cnpj: $('#txtCnpj').val(), _descricao: $("#txtDescricao").val() };    
    $.ajax({    
        url: '/GerenciarPDV/GravaEvento',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'applicatio/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(parametros),
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function () {

        }
    })
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void GravaEvento(string _cnpj, string _descricao)
{
    V99_WEBEntities db = new V99_WEBEntities();
    try
    {
        T_CRM_Evento evento = new T_CRM_Evento();

        evento.DE_Cnpj = _cnpj;
        evento.DE_Descricao = _descricao;

        db.T_CRM_Evento.Add(evento);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string erro = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Troque `public JsonResult GravaEvento(T_CRM_Evento _evento)` por `public JsonResult GravaEvento(FormCollection collection)`. O que acontece?

Comment: Eu troquei para void, pois é um método somente para inserção no BD. Tenho um outro bem semelhante a este e funciona. SE dou um alert com os valores que vem da página, eu teno os valores, mas quando chega na controller, está vazias. Vou editar e mostrar como ficou e mesmo assim nada. Não creio ser do bootstrap, pois no alert eu tenho os valores dos caras.

Comment: Cara, tenta colocar essas anotações no seu controller: `public JsonResult GravaEvento([FromBody]T_CRM_Evento _evento)`, por que você ta passando por POST. [Olha aqui](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: Po, mas tenho vários métodos semelhantes a esse que estão funcionando. Não entendo porque esse não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o método [***$.post***](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) que é mais simples e funciona perfeitamente:

***Javascript:***

```
function GravaEvento() {
    $.post("/Home/GravaEvento",
        {
            DE_Cnpj: $("#txtCnpj").val(),
            DE_Descricao: $("#txtDescricao").val(),
            DE_UsuProxAcao: $("#txtUsuarioProxAcao").val(),
            ID_TipoProxAcao: $("#txtDataCadastro").val(),
            DT_ProxAcao: $("#txtDataCadastro").val()
        },
       function (data) {

       }, 'json');
}
```

***Método:***

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GravaEvento(T_CRM_Evento t_crm_evento)
{
    return Json(new { Status = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

***Debug:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dessa forma funcionou, mas não entendo porque da outra forma não funcionou. Eu tenho todas as minhas funções da outra forma. Eu trabalho com html dinâmico, ou seja, no sucesso do ajax eu monto a minha página. Como fica usando da maneira que o harry postou?

Answer (score 0):

Tenho um exemplo de um tcc que fiz uma vez:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CalendarData(FormCollection f)
        {

            string datainicio = Request.Form["data_inicio"];
            string datafinal = Request.Form["data_final"];
            int sala_id = int.Parse(Request.Form["sala_id"]);
            int turno_id = int.Parse(Request.Form["turno_id"]);

            IList<Reserva> tasksList = new List<Reserva>();
            tasksList = ReservaDAO.getEvents(datainicio, datafinal, sala_id, turno_id);


            return Json(tasksList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Veja se ajuda. Faz o ajax da primeira forma que mandei.

Você pode pegar os campos no C# desta forma:

```
        string DE_Cnpj = Request.Form["DE_Cnpj"];
        string DE_Descricao = Request.Form["DE_Descricao"];
        string DE_UsuProxAcao = Request.Form["DE_UsuProxAcao"];
        string DT_ProxAcao = Request.Form["DT_ProxAcao"];
        int ID_TipoProxAcao = int.Parse(Request.Form["ID_TipoProxAcao"]);
```

Tenta assim:

```
function GravaEvento() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/GerenciarPDV/GravaEvento",
      type: "POST",
      data: { "DE_Cnpj": $("#txtCnpj").val(), "DE_Descricao": $("#txtDescricao").val(), "DE_UsuProxAcao": $("#txtUsuarioProxAcao").val(), "DE_UsuProxAcao": $("#txtProxAcao").val(), "DT_ProxAcao": $("#txtDataCadastro").val(), "ID_TipoProxAcao": $("#txtDataCadastro").val() },
      dataType: "json", 
      success: function(data){
            console.log(data); //aparece o retorno no terminal
      }
    });
}

GravaEvento(); //executa a funcao
```

Você pode também passar os paramentros de uma vez só no data desta forma:

```
data: $("form").serialize();
```

Comment: Continua vindo null

Comment: Parece coisa do demo. Continua vindo nulo tudo e não sei mais o que fazer.